# CNC Kitchens flow calibration script - too little extrusion

Tags: marlin, g-code

I created some G-code for my printer according to [Extrusion System Benchmark Tool for Fast Prints](https://www.cnckitchen.com/blog/extrusion-system-benchmark-tool-for-fast-prints).

Everything seems normal and the G-code preview also looks normal. However, the blobs that are supposed to be extruded are really slow. So slow in fact that I first thought the printer had crashed.

I checked the G-code of that particular move:

```
G1 Z10.5 E200 F4.99 ; Extrude
```

So 200 mm of filament are supposed to be extruded with a speed of 4.99 mm/min at 4 mm³/s, which seems slow to start with, but I calculated the volume of that move.

$4.99\ {mm}/min = 0.08\ {mm}/s$

$cross\ section\ of\ 1.75\ mm\ filament = 2.405\ {mm}^2$

$0.08\ {mm}/s * 2.405\ {mm}^2 = 0.2\ {mm}^3/s$ which is quite some way off the targeted 4.

It seems that the `F4.99` speed is applied to the movement of the Z-axis, not to the speed of the extrusion. My printer is Marlin based, so I wonder why the G-code is interpreted like that.

Comment: Have you used [`G91`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G091.html) command before? It puts the printer in relative movement mode.

Comment: ah interesting. the script actually puts a G90 at the start. but ill try it with G91.

Comment: ok G91 makes the whole patter look weird, but I found an `M83; set extruder to relative mode` but M82 should be relative extrusion moves according to the marlin gcode library. ill try it with M83 now.

Comment: I thought you are only doing this one particular line. `G91` won't work in fully generated G-code. Can you share your full G-code file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BhhzFAzG

this is the unaltered generated gecode from the excel tool

https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M083.html

Comment: It seems like everything is fine with your generated G-code. If the extruded filament is minimal, maybe something is not good with your printer. Have you printed anything before? Have you calibrated your E-steps?

Comment: hm, yeah the M82 doesnt seem to do anything. 
the printer prints fine, already for a long time. i just recently switched from idea maker to prusa slicer which allows me to test all these fancy calibration tools.

Comment: Looking at the G-code, there should be a little difference between each extruded line. Can you add a photo of the finished print to the question?

Comment: ill try to get a pic but the print takes ages. I managed to print 2/3 of the first row and it took something like 2 hours. but the pattern looks correct, the priming lines are printed correctly and the blobs are also extruded correctly.

im wondering if my printer has some special relative extrusion command. its a raise 3d pro btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141761/discussion-between-kosteklvp-and-sungod3k).

Comment: Except for that issue on the script, is your printer functional and printing parts normally? as if you are setting up the printer a mismatch in mm per step on the extruder is a common thing.

Comment: If you find that there is a problem with the tool, be sure to file an issue: https://github.com/CNCKitchen/ExtrusionSystemBenchmark/issues